# I wrote a discord bot with Python. It's not working on Glitch

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I made a discord bot with discord.py. It works very well in my PyCharm's terminal, when i upload it to the glitch most of the commands are still working but when i tried to create a text channel in "on_message" event, i got a error, i can create the channel but the rest of the code is not working. Here is the error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/app/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event

    await coro(*args, **kwargs)

  File "HashCubeSupport.py", line 102, in on_message

    await guild.categories[2].create_text_channel(name=name, overwrites=overwrites)

  File "/app/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 842, in create_text_channel

    return await self.guild.create_text_channel(name, overwrites=overwrites, category=self, reason=reason, **options)

  File "/app/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 869, in create_text_channel

    channel = TextChannel(state=self._state, guild=self, data=data)

  File "/app/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 107, in __init__

    self._update(guild, data)

  File "/app/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 131, in _update

    self._fill_overwrites(data)

  File "/app/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 294, in _fill_overwrites

    self._overwrites.append(_Overwrites(id=overridden_id, **overridden))

TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_new'
```

And here is the part of the code that causing error:

```
overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
            guild.roles[v]: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
            message.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
        }
name = f"test-{message.author.name}-{message.author.discriminator}"
await guild.categories[2].create_text_channel(name=name, overwrites=overwrites)
channel = guild.channels[-1].id
channel2 = client.get_channel(id=channel)
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.add_field(name="Test", value="test", inline=False)
await channel2.send(embed=embed)
```

If more code is necessary i can show more.

Answer (score -1):

Simply update discord.py

## Linux/macOS

python3 -m pip install -U discord.py

## Windows

py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py

Comment: Why are you sending a the same answer to all question u answered? It's irrelevant from my question.

Comment: I think its not, discord updated their api which caused a lot of trouble. And updating discord.py to 1.3.4 solves it. I guess by deleting/recreating your project you got the newer version :)